# how to select to count with mysql

Tags: mysql

i want to count with using select, count, and group by.
it work with MariaDB but not working wit MySQL.

i dont know if that version of mariadb or mysql but this code working in localhost but not working in my vps.

here my code

`SELECT date, COUNT(id_master_post) FROM master_post GROUP BY DAY(date) ASC;`

error i get.

> SELECT date, COUNT(id_master_post) FROM master_post GROUP BY DAY(date)
>   ASC LIMIT 0, 25 MySQL states: Documentation
>
> .#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'piratefiles.master_post.date' which is
>   not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Answer (score 2):

This is a common error in MySQL, which has different modes and hence different rules which may or may not be enforced.  In your case, you are selecting a column which does not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause (and also is not inside an aggregate function).  To fix this, make the column being selected and aggregated the same, i.e. use this:

```
SELECT DAY(date), COUNT(id_master_post)
FROM master_post
GROUP BY DAY(date);
```

But this would group all dates together based on the numeric day.  This may not be what you want, and in general I would recommend grouping on the date itself:

```
SELECT date, COUNT(id_master_post)
FROM master_post
GROUP BY date;
```

Comment: is that posible to showing full date not just day of that date? im using `datetime`. if im only using date it will count all of it, for ex if im posting 20 post taht day, it will record 20 data, but if using day(date) it will record just 1 data

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: OK...so what about that result set do you not like/want to change?

Comment: i want the result like my screenshot, but the code not working in my vps. if im using u code it will only showing day of that date.

Comment: My second query should generate that output.  Try it.